# how do i publish a chart built in bis to another sharepoint site

Tags: export, performancepoint, business-intelligence

I have been playing around with creating dashboards and charts using Performance Point services in the Dashboard Designer. I got the documentation on how to create them and built a couple in my BI SharePoint site. Now I would like to know what are my next steps to display one of my charts or dashboards in one of my other non-business intelligence centre SharePoint sites.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Chart WebPart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-the-chart-web-part-HA101889216.aspx#_Toc268792244) and configure it's data source as explained in this MSDN article.

[Create a chart by using the Chart Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-chart-by-using-the-chart-web-part-HA101889211.aspx)

e.g. You can connect this webpart to a Business Data Catalog

> What kinds of data sources can be used with the Chart Web Part?
>
> A
>   Chart Web Part can use one of the following data sources:
>
> Another Web Part. You can connect the Chart Web Part to another Web
>   Part that is capable of sending data. Examples of such Web Parts
>   include a Document Library or a Contacts list.
>
> A SharePoint List. You
>   can connect the Chart Web Part to a SharePoint list that is located in
>   the same site collection.
>
> A Business Connectivity Services component.
>   You can connect the Chart Web Part to a BCS component to display
>   external or line of business data.
>
> An Excel Services file. You can
>   connect the Chart Web Part to an Excel workbook that has been
>   published to Excel Services.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using SharePoint 2013 and the Chart web part is not available anymore. I have created my charts in Dashboard designer under PerformancePoint

Comment: @PieterDuToit check if this helps you http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/performancepoint-server/link-a-scorecard-kpi-to-an-analytic-chart-or-grid-using-dashboard-designer-HA010252493.aspx